# Best way to detect a person in a WebCamTexture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, face-recognition

Soon I will begin development on a mobile application in unity 5 that will use the devices native camera for the user to view. The big thing here is that while the camera is up, I need it to be able to recognize a person's face and compare it to a stored image of a face that will already be saved on the device to see if it is a match.

Also, I need to be able to recognize whether the center of the camera is pointing at a part of the person's body.

So all in all it needs to recognize a person's face and run a comparison on it, and if the face is recognized, it will then determine if the center of the camera is pointing at a part of the person's body.

My question is: Is there a good plugin for this sort of behavior? I know it will be a bit extensive but I am wondering how I would get this done. I am more focused on just facial recognition than the body issue so if that is the easier issue than I am good with focusing on that.

Comment: [This sounds like a task for opencv. And 5 years and a research team](http://xkcd.com/1425/)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds complicated and it envolved alot of diffirent processing techniques to achieve some resonable results. If I were you I would look into using the Face recognition module that comes with iOS and integrate that as a Native plugin, they can be used to extract and locate a face on a photo/feed. Then you got a photo next I would to is to rotate the photo and prepare it for comparison with other photos, that is "normalized" , you should normalize the colors and align it as much as possible. The final and most complicated step would be to analyse the face and compare with diffirent faces. I would recommend that you use OpenCV as suggested for that. I would try and analyse the structure of the face based on positioning a simple structure on the eyes, mouth, chin forehead and jaws, try and calculate the distance between these values and then you will have a way of roughly sorting the images that you want to match the face with since it doesn't make sense to do further processing on face images tha varies too much. Final step i would try to detect the eye color, the color of the skin and various other factors, these combined will give you some stats that can be used to determine how equal these photos are.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is you want. There is a open cv plugin with high price $95 on asset store: [OpenCV for Unity](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21088)

And here is face recognation demo video: https://youtu.be/u5aDbn5nRbY

Hope it will help.